# custom Wordpress pagination for a specific table

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a Wordpress website about streaming movies and I've created a table 'movies' in MYSQL. and when I want to show movies into my page it shows all the movies and I want just 12 per page. should I use the traditional pagination or there is a trick in wordpress that could help me.
wordpress pagination works fine only on posts table.
by the way I've used $wpdb.

```
global $wpdb;
  $movies = $wpdb->get_results("select * from movies");
  foreach ($movies as $key => $movie) {// code}
```

Comment: You should be using a custom poat type for it and not create custom tables ... that way you can use standard wp pagination and a multitude of other options wp has on the post types

Comment: No problem. I added that as an answer so you can accept it if you think it was useful :)

Comment: Added some references to aid you in building the CPT you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using custom post types instead of building custom tables.

That way you can use wp at its full extend and make use of all its options in post types.

You can read about it here https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Or you can use the Custom Post Types UI plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: why the downvote? :)) Isn't this the way to add custom post types in WP? Why would you add a custom table for movies???

Comment: it is the only way o do it, I read about it and practice it and it is the right way to do it.

Comment: this may help if someone have the same question: https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/

Comment: Ismail if you think my answer is helpful, please upvote and accept it. I am glad I could help

Comment: Sorry man but I can't upvote I am new to stack so I have less than 15 reputations